# Diferentes APKs para un rango de API LEVELs

Tags: android, android-studio

Me gustaría saber si esto es posible. Me gustaría desarrollar dos proyectos de android para una misma app, uno para las API LEVEL de 21 hasta 27 y otro de 28 en adelante.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cambiando únicamente el parámetro minSdkVersion es suficiente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si publico los 2 APKs a Google play de esta forma, ¿cuando un dispositivo tenga API LEVEL entre 21-27 se le instalara el apk del proyecto 1, y cuando tenga API LEVEL mayor o igual que 28 se le instalara el apk del proyecto 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Proyecto 1 :
minSdkVersion 21
versionCode 5

Proyecto 2 :
minSdkVersion 28
versionCode 7
```

> ¿cuando un dispositivo tenga API LEVEL entre 21-27 se le instalara el
> apk del proyecto 1, y cuando tenga API LEVEL mayor o igual que 28 se
> le instalara el apk del proyecto 2?

Exactamente así es como funciona la distribución en Google Play, aunque en el proyecto 1 no definas un `maxSdkVersion` si tienes otro .APK proyecto 2 con un `versionCode` mayor este será instalado en los dispositivos de acuerdo a la configuración que realizaste realizando un "Shadowing" sobre el .apk del proyecto 1.